# keyboard and mouse options/alternatives for a disabled person

Tags: keyboard, mouse

A good friend of mine went through some severe medical issues.  He was out of commission for over a year, but on the mend.  He is looking to get back to a more normal life, which includes working again.  He works in geographic information systems, so he needs to operate a computer.  Unfortunately, his medical issues has left him with tremors in his hands and has a very difficult time typing on a keyboard and using a mouse.

What hardware or software is out there that might help someone in this situation?

Comment: Your friend has my sympathy, but unfortunately your question is off topic (asking for both software and hardware recommendations).

Comment: @DavidPostill Its not off topic, thats why I asked it.  Asking what someone should use in this situation is very on topic.  People ask what hardware or software to use all the time.  Its not like asking which CPU is better, or what memory is a better value.

Comment: "What hardware or software is out there" You are asking us to recommend hardware and/or software. Both of those are explicitly off topic as per the help centre. With your rep you should know this. Please do your own research and then come back when you have specific questions about what you have found.

Answer (score 1):

Joysticks might be easier for your friend to use, and are cheap to try out.

There are pointer devices that attach to the head like a headset, and the cursor is guided by panning and tilting the head around.  A blow tube or bite activates the Click.

There are vertical keyboards that leave the hands resting and 90* to the desktop.  If the issue is from lifting the hands up, a vertical keyboard might help.

I won't mention specific models here because I don't have direct experience (and we're supposed to avoid product suggestions here) , but here are some useful sites :

https://abilitynet.org.uk/factsheets/keyboard-and-mouse-alternatives-and-adaptations

https://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/what-alternative-pointing-systems-are-available-someone-who-cannot-use-mouse

Answer (score 1):

Before looking at any additional peripherals to purchase, I'd suggest that he first take the time to look through the accessibility settings already available natively, e.g., Microsoft's [mobility assistive technologies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4456991).  And here's a [backup copy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NRvbotppp0BrY4eXAoq64gbNgDhCm4Ve/view?usp=drivesdk) hosted by me in case the web link dies, as <s>Microsoft's</s> they often tend to.